# opencv python connectedComponents select component per label

Tags: python, opencv, connected-components

I want to select each component of this image :

[image]

In practice, each and every triangle, by its labels. I don't figure out how.
I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('invMehs.png', -1)
imGray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, imBw = cv2.threshold(imGray, 250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

invBwMesh = cv2.bitwise_not(imBw)
Mask = np.ones(imBw.shape, dtype="uint8") * 255

connectivity = 4
output = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(imBw, connectivity, cv2.CV_32S)
num_labels = output[0]
labels = output[1]
stats = output[2]
centroids = output[3]
labels = labels + 1

b = ( labels == 1)
cv2.imwrite('tst.jpg',labels[b])
```

But the image is complety black :S
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The image you want save (labels[b]) only contains the thin lines (greylevel 1). When saving image using JPEG format, the compression algorithm smooths them, but since they have only 1 greylevel with the background, they are erased. That's why you get a black image

Saving in PNG format do not alter the image labels.

In order to keep all labels for each connected component (0 for the background), the code to write should be :

```
cv2.imwrite('labels.png',output[1])
```